# Extract values from multiple non-contiguous cells in a workbook and insert them into a table in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to pull values from non-contiguous cells (IE: F9, E15, G17, etc.) from a specific workbook and paste them into a table in a primary workbook. Each cell has data to be added to a specific column in said table.

I have hundreds of different files with the same layout (same cell locations) that I want to cycle through and add to a master table on the primary workbook.

I need information from 12 cells per file. I have attempted arrays, creating variables, and messing with ranges. I was able to get to the point where I create a different variable for each cell I want data from and then, one-by-one, insert them into a specific cell in the primary workbook. This is far from automatic and doesn't include inserting each value under a specific column in my table.

The most functional macro I've been able to create seems clunky and inefficient and does not prove to be a solution for my primary problems: automation, efficiency.

```vb
Sub data_pull()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ - workbook that data is pulled from")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ - workbook that data is put to")

'Pulling data through variables
RSS = x.Sheets(1).Range("F9").Value
RSE1_F = x.Sheets(1).Range("E13").Value
RSE1_B = x.Sheets(1).Range("F13").Value
RSE2_F = x.Sheets(1).Range("E14").Value
RSE2_B = x.Sheets(1).Range("F14").Value
TI = x.Sheets(1).Range("F20").Value
SI = x.Sheets(1).Range("F30").Value
FIBI = Split(x.Sheets(1).Range("F36").Value, "/") 'Cell has two values separated by a "/"
PEN = x.Sheets(1).Range("E40").Value

'Putting data through predefined variables
y.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = RSS
y.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value = RSE1_F
y.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Value = RSE1_B
y.Sheets(1).Range("D1").Value = RSE2_F
y.Sheets(1).Range("E1").Value = RSE2_B
y.Sheets(1).Range("F1").Value = TI
y.Sheets(1).Range("G1").Value = SI
y.Sheets(1).Range("H1").Value = FIBI(0)     
y.Sheets(1).Range("I1").Value = FIBI(1)     
y.Sheets(1).Range("J1").Value = PEN

x.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It is completely handled by calling for specific cell locations and does not append any data to a table specifically. I have a hunch that I could define a range with each cell location and then loop through that range, appending each cell to the desired table location.

Comment: You don't really even need the intermediate variables such as `RSS` - it's just as clear to use something like `y.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets(1).Range("F9").Value`  Probably worth declaring a couple of worksheet variables so you don't have to keep typing `x.Sheets(1)` and `y.Sheets(1)`

Comment: I understand that. I suppose I just formatted it this way to give myself more clarity.

Comment: Structurally, I would separate your code into 2 subs.  The outer one to perform all the workbook opening and closing and the worksheet identification.  Then the inner one to move the data using the worksheet objects that are passed in. This allows a bit more flexibility in opening and closing multiple workbooks.

Comment: _into a table  in a primary workbook_. Is that table a [ListObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) ?

Comment: If you want to be able to process multiple workbooks into a single table,  you're going to have to change your target references to `y.Sheets(1).Cells(1,nextfreerow) = x.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value`.  nextfreerow is an integer  that can be gotten by `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option for collecting cell values from a non-contiguous range is by defining the whole range, copying into an array and pasting in your uniform output region:

```
Option Explicit
Sub General_Testing()
        
    ' > Var
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim RG As Range
    Dim CL As Range
    Dim RGarr
    Dim I As Long
    
    ' > Change to your workbooks/Sheets
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    ' > Source Data range
    Set RG = wsInput.Range("$F$6,$E$13:$F$14,$F$20:$F$21")
    ReDim RGarr(1 To RG.Cells.Count)
    
    ' > Move into array
    I = 1
    For Each CL In RG.Cells
        RGarr(I) = CL.Value
        I = I + 1
    Next CL
    
    With wsOutput
        ' > Array to output range
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(RGarr)) = RGarr
        
        ' > last couple oddball values
        .Range("H1:I1").Value = Split(wsInput.Range("F36"), "/")
        .Range("J1").Value = wsInput.Range("F40").Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```

If you want, you could easily do the whole thing including your split cell in the one array, just check for delimiter and increment I twice.

This is what is looks like:

Input:
[image]
Output:
[image]

---

**Method 2:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub General_Testing()
        
    ' > Var
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim RG As Range
    Dim CL As Range
    Dim RGarr
    Dim I As Long
    
    ' > Change to your workbooks/Sheets
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    ' > Source Data range
    Set RG = wsInput.Range("$F$6,$E$13:$F$14,$F$20:$F$21,$F$36,$E$40")
    ReDim RGarr(1 To RG.Cells.Count)
    
    ' > Move into array
    I = 1
    For Each CL In RG.Cells
        If InStr(1, CL.Value, "/") > 0 Then
            ' > String must be split
            ReDim Preserve RGarr(1 To UBound(RGarr) + 1)
            RGarr(I) = Split(CL.Value, "/")(0)
            I = I + 1
            RGarr(I) = Split(CL.Value, "/")(1)
            I = I + 1
        Else
            ' > String must not be split
            RGarr(I) = CL.Value
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next CL
    
    With wsOutput
        ' > Array to output range
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(RGarr)) = RGarr
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: since the `For Each CL...` method can be slow, I  would probably create a dictionary or array of coordinates, like: `Array("6-6","13-5","13-6" ... )` then import the whole range into an array `range("A1:F40")` then reference each of those coordinates to build output array.  -> I think this would be the fastest performance ... if somewhat less easy to edit in the future.

Comment: This is more of the solution that I had in mind. I will go ahead and give it a shot. If it works, depending on how fast it runs, I'll try creating the coordinate array. Thanks for the in depth response!

Comment: FYI: if you want to generate a list of all the cells in a specific range, just select all the individual cells on the sheet then in the immediate window, type: `Debug.print selection.address`

Comment: This just changed my life.

Comment: Yup your first solution seems to work pretty well. Only difficulty I'm having is splitting that bizarre cell. Is there a way to split it and append Rgarr before inputting the array into the workbook?

Comment: Yes. One Second

Comment: Okay, I've edited to do in one loop without those last oddball bits. See above

Comment: You are stellar! One small problem though. One of my cells includes a date and thus a "/". Is there a way to define what the value should "look like". Similar to like regex? Just a bit of info on the layouts -  (Date: XX/XX/XXX) (Cell to be split: XXXX.X/XXXX.X)

Comment: Absolutely, Regex is a great option. Or you can do it with a few different checks. **>>>** If you're going to do multiple checks though I would store CL.value as a variable to speed up script a little like: `CelVal = CL.value` **>>>** Just link together a few conditions like: `If InStr(1, CelVal, "/") > 0 And Mid(CelVal, 5, 1) = "/" And IsNumeric(Mid(CelVal,1, 4)) = true then...` Or some such thing.